# Is there a way to use the previous value of a computed Angular signal?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, signals

I want to add each new value from signal A to the list value of signal B, similar to what you can do with the scan operator in RxJS.
Ideally I'd want something like this: `signalB = computed((value) => [...value, signalA()])`. Can I somehow do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework doesn't propose something out-of-the-box, but the `ngextension` library has a neat [`extendedComputed`](https://ngxtension.netlify.app/utilities/signals/computed/)

```
import { extendedComputed } from 'ngxtension/computed';

const multiplier = signal(2);
const count = signal(1);

const result = extendedComputed<number>((previousValue) => {
  // only compute when multiplier is even
  if (multiplier() % 2 === 0) {
    return count() * multiplier();
  }
  return previousValue;
});
```

Comment: looks like `extendedComputed` is going to be deprecated